# Set Django's RequestFactory() method to equal 'POST'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

Example view function:

```
def example_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        print(request.session['Key'])

        return HttpResponse("Success")
```

Test case to test view:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase
from website.views import example_view

class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_example(self):

        # Create request and session
        request = RequestFactory()
        request.session = SessionStore()

        request.session['Key'] = "Value"

        response = example_view(request)

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

urls.py file in case anyone asks for it:

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('example', views.example_view, name="example_view"),
]
```

Error Response:

```
AttributeError: 'RequestFactory' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Without:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

this works as expected.

How do I set the request.method equal to post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestFactory` gives you a factory, not a request, to get the request you must call the factory as you'd do with the Django testing client:

```py
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.post('/your/view/url')
response = example_view(request)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that, but was using RequestFactory incorrectly as you pointed out.